# Post a message on console when users come online or go offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to use the following code but somehow it doesn't work at all. The idea is to have a server log on console for users coming online and going offline.

```
bot.on("Presence", usr => {
    if (usr.status == 'offline'){
        console.log(`${usr.username} is offline`);
    } else if (usr.status == 'online') {
        console.log(`${usr.username} is online`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I know that is JS but you really should put the name of the programming language you're coding in and add it as a tag otherwise nobody will find your question. Secondly if you check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=presenceUpdate), the name of the event is `presenceUpdate`.

```
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status){
        console.log(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.presence.status}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Wright. Sorry I haven't tagged it. I actually did this and even something similar but get it as "undefined is now online", etc. How would I go about fixing it. Thanks again.

Comment: AMAZING! That seems to fix it. However, it does push out two notifications on the console. Two lines of the same thing always.

Eg: 
magn3to is now online
magn3to is now online

Comment: Hm you sure you don't have two `presenceUpdate` listeners in your code. Or in another file running

Comment: Nope, I have nothing else listening for presenceUpdate. Let me actually run this alone and see what happens.

Comment: Still getting two of the same always. Not sure why or how though.

Comment: @GodIsGhost Yeah, you're right I tried it as well and I get the response 3 times. Could be a bug.

Comment: @Wright This might be because that particular user could be in multiple guilds and bot also is watching in those. So if a user comes online bot is triggered from 3 different guilds, hence 3 times. Just thinking of possibility, not sure